# Importing jfeinstein10's SlidingMenu Project

Tags: android, import, slidingmenu

I'm new to Android and I would like to try jfeinstein10's library which can be found here:
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues

Unfortunately I have problems importing the library. I checked [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OT76zDIeBe8) video out. I set the project's build path to the Google API. In the videos all the errors disappear.
As minTargetSdk I selected Android 2.2. (API 8), targetSdlVersion is 17.
In my case I still have some errors in the SlidingMenu class:

1)HONEYCOMB cannot be resolved or is not a field

2)LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE cannot be resolved or is not a field

3)LAYER_TYPE_NONE cannot be resolved or is not a field

4)The Method getLayerType() is undefined for the type View

5)The Method setLayerType(int, null) is undefined for the type View

Any suggestions how I can fix these issues?
Thank you in advance

Cheers

Comment: Did you add the support libraries and `ActionBarSherlock`? You need to make sure you're using the `support-v13` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the project build target (right mouse-click on project, then select properties, then Android) set to Google APIs v17.

I don't think you can set it to minTargetSdk of Android API 8.

Comment: minTargetSdk = 11 I guess. But how can I then ensure backward compatibility?

Comment: If I set the Google API to 16 or 17 it works. Thanks. I left the minTargetSdk as it was.